# Is there anything to replace SocketHubAppender in log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm looking for anything to replace SocketHubAppender Class in log4j2.
SocketHubAppender class supports logging server function through tcp/ip socket easily from log4j1.
I've been using this class for a long time.

I have to update log4j2 from log4j1 for some security issues.
But, I couldn't find it yet.

Is there anything to replace SocketHubAppender class or
Do I need to change logging library?

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.